# switch statement case '1' already in use - HandmadeHero 138

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am following the HandmadeHero series and I get some weird behaviour in a switch statement that does not come up in the video. It is most likely a thing that was added to the VS2015 Community Edition compiler.
The problem occurs in the code loading a .wav file (video from [Day 138](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSxUBaoomy0) at around 00:18:00).

For different chunk types in the [RIFF format](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html)  there is an `enum` defined:

```
#define RIFF_CODE(a, b, c, d) (((uint32)(a) << 0) || ((uint32)(b) << 8) || ((uint32)(c) << 16) || ((uint32)(d) << 24))
enum                           /*!< listing of different possible chunk IDs */
{
    WAVE_ChunkID_fmt_ = RIFF_CODE('f', 'm', 't', ' '),  /**< standard sub-chunk id */
    WAVE_ChunkID_data = RIFF_CODE('d', 'a', 't', 'a'),  /**< data chunk */
    WAVE_ChunkID_RIFF = RIFF_CODE('R', 'I', 'F', 'F'),  /**< RIFF chunk id */
    WAVE_ChunkID_WAVE = RIFF_CODE('W', 'A', 'V', 'E'),  /**< WAVE chunk id */
};
```

In the actual file loading code there is a `switch`-statement:

```
uint32 ChunkType = GetType(Iter);
switch(ChunkType)
{
    case WAVE_ChunkID_fmt_:
    {
        WAVE_fmt* fmt = (WAVE_fmt*)GetChunkData(Iter);
        break;
    }
    case WAVE_ChunkID_data:
    {
         SampleData = (int16*)GetChunkData(Iter);
         break;
    }
}
```

The line `case WAVE_ChunkID_data:` gives me the error code

```
> w:\code\handmade_asset.cpp(270): error C2196: case value '1' already
> used
```

Can someone figure out whats going on there? As I mentioned, the same code is used in the video (and I have access to the actual code by Casey as well) and the error does not occur in the video.

Thanks :)

Comment: Seems that WAVE_ChunkID_data and WAVE_ChunkID_fmt_ both equal 1. Have you tried just printing them both out to confirm?

Comment: Seems that `WAVE_ChunkID_fmt_` and `WAVE_ChunkID_data` are both evaluating to 1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define RIFF_CODE(a, b, c, d) (((uint32)(a) << 0) || ((uint32)(b) << 8) || ((uint32)(c) << 16) || ((uint32)(d) << 24))
```

The above macro makes use of the logical OR operator. So the result will always be 0 or 1 when converted to an integer. I assume it's a typo, and the intent was to write it as follows:

```
#define RIFF_CODE(a, b, c, d) (((uint32)(a) << 0) | ((uint32)(b) << 8) | ((uint32)(c) << 16) | ((uint32)(d) << 24))
```

Now it actually preforms a bitwise combination of its arguments.